# Voicemeeter Banana - smoothing volume transition

Tags: windows-7, audio, macros, unicode, volume-mixer

So I'm trying to figure out if I need to somehow loop a script in the "request for button on trigger in" box. Currently I've got strip(4).gain+=1.0 assigned to the volume up key which means I still have to tap the volume key repeatedly. I would love to be able to hold the volume key down and have the gain smoothly rise when the volume+ key is held down like it does when volume keys are hooked to A1, and I was wondering if there's some additional script I could add to achieve that? Also I'm assuming the same additional script, if it exists, would apply to lowering the volume smoothly?

Comment: Sorry not sure how I got that into my head. I think I may have been conflating two separate ideas.

Comment: Looks like there's a .FadeTo function listed in the user manual I'll try that out.

Answer (score 1):

The .FadeTo was exactly what I was looking for. Pretty simple really. Just needed to enter strip(4).FadeTo= (12.0, 2000); into the "Request for button ON/ Trigger In:" box and then strip(4).gain+=0 into the Request for button OFF/ Trigger Out:" box. 12 being the highest value of gain you can set the fader to, and -60 the lowest. While 2000 is the number of milliseconds it takes to reach the specified volume level. strip(4).gain+=0 stops the volume from continuing to rise after the volume up key is released. The button type does need to be set to "push button", but that about sums it up.

Comment: Props to you for taking the time to post the solution when you found it, I use the same software and didn't even know it provided such capabilities.

Comment: Much appreciated. As far as I can tell it's got full macro support for up to 4 dedicated macro slots. The only functions I've ended up using are .mute .gain and .FadeTo... Here's a link to the user manual if you ever feel like checking out it's full capabilities, which are actually pretty impressive by the way. https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/VoicemeeterBanana_UserManual.pdf

Comment: Strike the 4 slots thing. You can expand the window to fit 70 different dedicated slots.

Comment: That's great, I appreciate the extra info! Welcome to the community too, I reckon you'll fit right in here if you do stick around :)

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome. As the weather get's colder I find I'm spending more and more time indoors on my P.C., so I'm sure I'll be back around at least off and on. ;-)